# How do I make my box go from centre to smoothly transition across to the top left after a 1 second set interval?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to do a smooth transition logo from the centre of my browser to the top, left corner after my set interval timer has done 1 second.

What is the best approach for this?

Current code below.

```js
var timesRun = 0;


window.onload = loader()

function loader(){
    var newinterval = setInterval(function(){
        timesRun += 1;
        if(timesRun === 1){
            clearInterval(newinterval);
            moveLogo();
         
    }
}, 1000); 
}


function moveLogo(){
   // ????????????
    const logo = document.querySelector('.box')
    logo.className = 'left'
    logo.style.transition = 'all 0.5s';
    logo.style.transform = 'translate(0%, 0%)';
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 220px;
  height:80px;
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
};
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to make some real nice animations, look for [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/). You will be able to achieve super smooth and more complex movements with lesser efforts than trying to code it all from scratch. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = loader()

function loader() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    moveLogo();
  }, 1000);
}

function moveLogo() {
  document.querySelector('.box').classList.add('move-logo');
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 220px;
  height:80px;
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.move-logo {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: left 1s, top 1s, margin 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

It would be nice to review the way you are centering this `<div>`. I particularly try to avoid `position: absolute`, but that will depend on your case.

**Edit 1:**

Another option is to use pure CSS, without JavaScript.

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 220px;
  height:80px;
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.move-logo {
  animation-name: move-from-center;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

@keyframes move-from-center {
  0% {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box move-logo"></div>
```

Comment: Why not suggesting a `setTimeout`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Good observation! I copied his example and edited focused on CSS. I will improve it.

Comment: I would have placed the `document.querySelector` part directly in the `setTimeout` and squarely removed the `moveLogo` function. -- But the CSS only solution is great ;) +1